# multiple pair wise nonparametric comparisons

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, bonferroni

is it possible to perform multiple pair wise nonparametric
comparisons (generally using a Mann–Whitney test) and
adjust the significance level used for the decision criteria
using a Bonferroni-type adjustment through SAS software? How can i do that?

Comment: Be aware that if you are asking for SAS code, that is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

A quick, approximate way to do this is to...

1. Use a `data` step to create a new variable, `rank`, equal to the ranks of the dependent variable.
2. Use `proc glm` to fit a suitable ANOVA model with `rank` as the response. Include `lsmeans` statements for the comparisons and adjustment procedure you desire.

This works because the Mann-Whitney test is essentially a $t$ test on the ranks. When you have several groups, it changes the M-W results somewhat (because the M-W test does the rankings only within two groups at a time), but the underlying idea is still there.